# How to "edit" all numeric values in excel

Tags: pandas, pow

I was trying recently to add 2^() to all numeric valus in excel (on the exact cell):

```
df = pd.read_csv("counts.csv")
for x in df.iteritems():
        df.loc[:, df.columns != 'Ensembl_ID']
        df = df.iloc[0:]
df= df(2**x)
```

Getting  -- >TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'int' and 'tuple'
I am not sure how do I put 2 in power (number), and I tried to remove the first column and row (which are str)

Comment: `df[df.select_dtypes('number').columns] = 2 ** df.select_dtypes('number')`

Comment: _and I tried to remove the first column and row (which are str)_ Is the data in your columns not homogenous?